# From backslash to slash (to create folders named with number)

Tags: python, string, mkdir

I had a bad problem with these two: "\" and "/" in Windows, obviously :\

I need to replace **all** \ occurrence  in /, so I can use replace() because doesn't work with this "\6" for example.

What I have to do? **I want "only" use mkdir()** to replicate a structure of folders (without files) from one location to another. So I use mainly os.walk() and mkdir(); everything work well till is found a folder named with numeber. Infact mkdir can do this:

mkdir("C:\folder") and also mkdir("C:\newfolder") but NOT mkdir("C:\6") for example, because it would mkdir("C:/6").

But I don't know how to pass to it a path with slash and not backslash, because, as I said, I don't write manually the path, but come from "dirname" of  os.walk().

I know that exist os.path.normcase and os.path.normpath, but they convert forward slashes to backward slashes.

**I need "only" to replicate a structure of folders, and unfortunately, many folders are named with number....What can I do?**

Thank You Very Much

P.S.: Path are not simple like example... a more realistic example could be "D:\main\folder\blue\sky\34"

Comment: Last time I looked '/' works fine on windows too. No need to muck around with backslashes

Answer (score 3):

construct your paths with os.path, then it's platform agnostic and you'll avoid these issues.

For example, `mkdir(os.path.join(r"C:\", "6"))`

or `os.path.join(r"D:\", "main", "folder", "red", "34")`

Comment: It's not possible, I believe... path are not write manually and are not so simple... them are like "D:\main\folder\red\34"

Comment: os.path.join("C:", "6") doesn't work.  That results in "C:6".  Explanation is here: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in Python string literals.  To actually use a literal backslash in a string, you must escape the backslash with a backslash.

Example:

```
foo = "c:\\bar"
```

Your problem with folder names using numbers is that Python will interpret a backslash followed by a valid octal number as a character with a character code = that octal number.  See http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals.

To illustrate the problem with "c:\6":

```
>>> len("c:\6")
3
>>> len("c:\\6")
4
```

Character code 6 is an [ACK character](http://www.asciitable.com/) rather than a human-readable string representation of the number "6".

You should still use os.path.join() to construct paths that you use with mkdir.  Python will take care of platform-dependent slash behavior (except for drive letters...grr!  see http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Example:

```
>>> os.path.join("D:\\", "main", "folder", "blue", "sky", "34")
'D:\\main\\folder\\blue\\sky\\34'
```

Comment: How I can use os.path.join? path is already formed from os.walk, because I have to replicate a structure of folders..

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem then.  You should post an example of your code so it's clear where your problem lies.  Is it that you're having trouble using <string obj>.replace()?  If so, then instead of converting "\" to "/" before doing a string replace, just make sure to escape backslashes.  
>>> path_from_walk = "c:\\6"
>>> path_from_walk.replace("\\6", "\\foo")
'c:\\foo'

Answer (score 1):

In a string, backslash-something is a digraph, a character code for something else.

```
mkdir('c:\newfolder')
```

fails because '\n' is a newline character - you have told your computer to make a new folder named 'c:{newline}ewfolder', which is not a valid folder name.

To make it work properly, you would have to do one of

```
mkdir(r'c:\newfolder')  # the preceding r makes the string raw,
                        # so digraphs are not processed

mkdir('c:\\newfolder')  # \\ is the digraph for a single backslash
```

.

**Edit:** try this; do you have any problems with it?

```
import os

def dupTree(src, dest):
    src  = os.path.abspath(src)
    dest = os.path.abspath(dest)

    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
        relPath = os.path.relpath(root,src)
        for d in dirs:
            newDir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dest, relPath, d))
            os.mkdir(newDir)
```

Comment: mmm... I know all this... BUT, as I said, I don't write path with keyboard.... path come from os.walk so I can't use raw, and I can't use double-backslash.